# React Native - ios device won't connect to debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The error I am receiving is: `Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=client timed out. Are you running node proxy? If you are running on the device, check if you have the right IP address in RCTWebSocketExecutor.m`

I have tried changing from localhost to my computer's ip address as mentioned in other stackoverflow post's but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Try turning off the debugger through you're dev menu and turn it back on once you rebuild the app.

Comment: Tried that still no luck.

Comment: @itajenglish did you find a fix? For me I can use the debugger in the simulator and can run on the device but cannot debug on the device. Thanks

Comment: @Vyga Yeah I figured out my issue was that whenever I was connected to public wifi network my phone can't access the localhost network the debugger is running on. It will only work on my own personal private network at home.